# K8s - secrets volume projection doesn't create file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have problem with deploying of multiple secrets from template `deployment.yaml`. For some reason, when my app try to find the file within deployment, it cannot be found. Secrets are taken by groovy script from gopass.

Here is actual simplified version of file (indication levels should be proper)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "test-app"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "some-container"
        image: "imgtag"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-secrets
          mountPath: /app/secrets
      volumes:
      - name: app-secrets
        projected:
          sources:
          - secret:
            name: secret1
          - secret:
            name: secret2
```

Old version (this properly created `private_key.pem`):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "test-app"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "some-container"
        image: "imgtag"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: app-secrets
            mountPath: /app/secrets
      volumes:
      - name: app-secrets
        secret:
          secretName: secret1
```

`secrets.groovy`:

```
def secrets() {
    [
        [type: "fromFile", name: "secret1", key: "private_key.pem", gopassPath: "firstGopassPath"],
        [type: "fromFile", name: "secret2", key: "credentials.txt", gopassPath: "secondGopassPath"]
    ]
}

return this
```

When I added delay (to avoid crashing), then I see that these files just weren't mounted anywhere.

Description of pod says that:

(this was before updating kube client)

```
Volumes:
  app-secrets:
  <unknown>
```

(this was after updating kube client to 1.18 from 1.12.1)

```
Volumes:
  app-secrets:
    Type:  Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
```

--UPDATE--

`kubectl get secret secret1 -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  old_private_key.pem: somekey
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-22T15:31:43Z"
  name: jpd-sales-force-private-key
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "137791226"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/secret1
  uid: a4f71c36-81d0-44f8-87a0-a6100c6f9f01
type: Opaque
```

(note: I was trying to rename file - the original was private_key.pem, here: old_private_key.pem, and private_key.pem in original post is in real new name, so it looks like new name of file didn't appear).

Does any of you have idea what may be wrong?

Comment: can you share one of your secrets yaml? `kubectl get secret secret1 -o yaml`

Comment: @Shahriar sure, please find it in the post.

Comment: @Shahriar Is there any error message? Have you checked any relevant logs?

Comment: @OhHiMark what kind of error you mean? I don't see any... The first error I got (or at least first about which I know) is when app fails on missing file.

Comment: @OldShaterhan Do you want to say that your k8s version is 1.12.1? Have you considered upgrading to the latest stable 1.18?

Comment: @OhHiMark only client version was 1.12.1 (what I updated), server side is 1.17. Finally I found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my problem:

1. Deleting of old secret (it made the filename change fixed): `kubectl delete secret secret1`
2. name of `secret1` and `secret2` were one level too low. Improved version:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: "test-app"
spec:
 template:
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: "some-container"
       image: "imgtag"
       volumeMounts:
       - name: app-secrets
         mountPath: /app/secrets
     volumes:
     - name: app-secrets
       projected:
         sources:
         - secret:
             name: secret1
         - secret:
             name: secret2
```

Comment: This will not work. You don't point out which key from the secret should be used.